# How to load FlexGrid on view height change Angular2

Tags: angular, grid, wijmo5

I have FlexGrid in a section. The section is collapsed by default. When it is expanded, grid is not showing data. Grid is not getting the view height change on expansion. How can I load grid after the section expansion?

Comment: Please add some code that demonstrates what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling FlexGrid's Refresh() method when the section is expanded to update the grid's layout.